# How to open a browser window in Java without the addressbar

Tags: java, browser, address-bar

Is there any way to open a new window in Java without the addressbar?
I'm looking for a Java API similiar to the JavaScript window.open() where you can specify the new window "features".

I know I can use Desktop.browse() or even the more adavance [BrowserLauncher2](http://browserlaunch2.sourceforge.net/),
Still both APIs don't give me the option to specify any features for the new browser window.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Lobo](http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp).  If the API doesn't meet your needs, you can use their source code to write your own browser.